# Method with same name in Derived class wrongly called in Parent class while using inheritance in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, super, magic-methods

I have the following code

```
class Parent(bytes):
    def __init__(self, validate=True):
        super().__init__()
        if validate:
            self.validate()

    def validate(self):
        print("Validation of Parent")
        return self

class Derived(Parent):
    def __init__(self, validate=True):
        super().__init__()
        if validate:
            self.validate()

    def validate(self):
        print("Validation of Derived")
        return self

object = Derived()
```

It is also required that **init**() has to be called in Derived to unpack different types of data.
Also validate=True has to be passed into **init**() as argument and this part has to stay to avoid flake8 & pylint warning check:

```
if validate:
    self.validate()
```

And my current output is:

```
Validation of Derived
Validation of Derived
```

But I want **expected output** to be:

```
Validation of Parent
Validation of Derived
```

**Is there a way to modify how the validate() method is called in Parent class to avoid this error?**

Comment: You could rename the method to `__validate()`, so that it gets name-mangled differently in each class - effectively making each version callable only from the class that defined it.

Comment: `self` is an instance of `Derived`, so `self.validate()` is *always* going to call `Derived.validate`, even if used inside `Parent.__init__`.

Comment: @jasonharper, thank you, that is a really good idea.

Comment: Yes, design your code properly, like [quamrana](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68068708/1126841) has demonstrated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `Parent` class `__init__()` already calls `validate()` your derived class need not. But, your version of `validate` should:

```py
class Parent(bytes):
    def __init__(self, validate=True):
        super().__init__()
        if validate:
            self.validate()

    def validate(self):
        print("Validation of Parent")
        return self

class Derived(Parent):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # do specialised setup here.

    def validate(self):
        super().validate()
        print("Validation of Derived")
        return self

object = Derived()
```

Output as expected.

**Update:** Just be aware that I've shown the call to `super().__init__()` first, which, of course calls down to your `validate()`. You may actually need to perform the `specialised setup` *first* and *then* do the super call to init.

Comment: In my project, the __init__() has to be called in Derived to unpack different types of data.
So if possible, do you have any way that doesn't required removing __init__() in the Derived class?

Comment: Well of course, but you didn't indicate in your question that the `Derived.__init__()` did anything special. I shall update....

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but if it is required that I have to add validate=True into the __init() of Derived and this part has to stay
if validate:
            self.validate()
The the sequence of validaton will be called 2 times, is it possible for it to be called only 1 time?

Comment: See my update. I use `*args, **kwargs` to pass any parameters onwards. The `Derived.__init__()` does not need to directly call `validate()`. We leave this to the super class.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

I will mark this as the perfect result.

You are awesome